# Running powershell script on network machine

Tags: batch-file, cmd, powershell-2.0

I am running a Powershell script from a bat file. These 2 files are placed on a network server and I am trying to run these on network server from my machine by accessing network server folder. I get following error:

> CMD doesn't support UNC paths as current directories.

When I execute bat file , it tries to read script file from path

> C:\Windows\System32

not from current directory which is set in bat file.

**This script and bat file work fine when I run on my local machine.**

I tried finding this on Google and possible solutions need to change some settings on network server which is not possible in my case.

What could be possible solution for this?
I am using PowerShell 2.0
Here is my bat file to run Powershell script

```
setlocal & pushd .

:getting current directory  
 cd /d %~dp0

Powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned  
Powershell.exe . '%CD%\Hotfix-Automation-Installer.ps1' crpt    
exit /B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like the message says: CMD doesn't support UNC paths as current directories, so you shouldn't use `%CD%` or `.` when you're working with UNC paths.

However, what's actually preventing your PowerShell script from being run is the single quotes around the path:

```
Powershell.exe . '%CD%\Hotfix-Automation-Installer.ps1' crpt
```

Single quotes are not valid quoting characters in CMD, so your script is actually trying to run the PowerShell script from a subfolder `'` in the current directory. Which doesn't exist.

Change your script to this, and it should work just fine:

```
@echo off

powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "%~dp0Hotfix-Automation-Installer.ps1" crpt
```

Comment: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass" will work, but I prefer "RemoteSigned" then adding specific UNC paths to the Intranet Zone, for running unsigned scripts from those locations. See option #2 found here: http://setspn.blogspot.com/2011/05/running-powershell-scripts-from-unc.html